# Serving Angular front end with Flask does not render images

Tags: angular, image, flask

I have created an Angular website that makes requests to a back-end I developed using Flask. My first mission was to serve the website using Flask.

Following this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692749/angular-4-frontend-with-python-flask-backend-how-to-render-simple-index-page), I managed to serve my website on the Flask server.

The only problem is that the images I used in the website do not appear. Before serving the website with Flask, everything was OK. But not I get errors like so:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/assets/img/green_circle.png 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

This happens for all the images I want to show. My folder structure is like this:

```
mainFolder
    |-static
    |   |- contains all js and css files
    |   |- assets (CONTAINS IMAGES)
    |-templates
    |   |-index.html
    |-server.py
```

My `index.html` file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="./">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="CoreUI - Free Angular Admin Template">
  <meta name="author" content="Łukasz Holeczek">
  <meta name="keyword" content="Bootstrap,Admin,Template,Free,Angular,Dashboard,Typescript">
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">
    <title>WINGS Smart Parking System</title>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-118965717-3"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    // Shared ID
    gtag('config', 'UA-118965717-3');
    // Angular ID
    gtag('config', 'UA-118965717-4');
  </script>
</head>
<body class="app">
  <!-- App Loading... -->
<script src="/static/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/static/polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script>
<script src="/static/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="/static/styles.js"></script>
<script src="/static/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="/static/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/static/main.js"></script>
<script src="/static/views-dashboard-dashboard-module.js"></script>
<script src="/static/views-buttons-buttons-module.js"></script>
<script src="/static/views-chartjs-chartjs-module.js "></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `server.py`, add a `static_proxy` to ensure that supporting files are served.

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET'])
def static_proxy(path):
  return send_from_directory('./', path)


@app.route('/')
def root():
  return send_from_directory('./', 'index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # This is used when running locally only. When deploying use a webserver process 
  # such as Gunicorn to serve the app.
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
  return 'An internal error occurred [main.py] %s' % e, 500
```

### Additional resource

[**Python (Flask) serving Angular project's index.html file**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53824239/1164465)

### Extra note from asker

In order to be able to make requests from the Flask server serving the angular front-end to itself, in `app.run()` you must also set `threaded=True`.

Comment: I tried this and loaded the home page well.
But when I try to navigate the angular application paths from the browser url, it returns a 404.
Does that work for you?