# How to update index.html file to add static to its path during build process?

Tags: python, angular, flask

I want to add `/static/` in front of all the paths in index.html. Since Flask looks for static files inside the `/root_folder/static` folder. Even though I have placed all the files inside the `static` folder, it is unable to get the files as the path in the index.html file is not correct.

My current directory structure in Flask looks like this

```
web_ui
    src
       -static
       -web_app.py
    logs
    config
```

This is what the path to various files in index.html looks like.

```
  <script src="assets/js/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to have

```
  <script src="/static/assets/js/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

is there any way to change the angular.json file? I have changed the output directory

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../web_ui/src/static/",  #<----
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/main.js",
              "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"
            ]
```

I have looked into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692749/angular-4-frontend-with-python-flask-backend-how-to-render-simple-index-page) but the person has not explained how to do it. Do I have to manually change the path?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if there's an Angular way to do this, but there is a Flask way to change the directory where static files are loaded. See [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.static_folder).

```py
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="")  # Not "static"
```

Comment: this will not work with angular as index.html is dynamically generated during the build process and you are not supposed to manually edit it.